# Prevent model from rolling when applying quaternion

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

How do I rotate a model and keep the model from rolling sideways? Using quaternions work fine when applied directly on an axis. As soon as I do more than one axis, the model starts twisting.

Original orientation is 0,0,1
[image: Original orientation is 0,0,1.]

Rotated to 1,0,0 works fine.
[image: Rotated to 1,0,0 works fine.]

Rotated to 1,1,0 does not work. It starts rolling/twisting around its original z axis.
[image: Rotated to 1,1,0 does not work. It starts rolling/twisting around its original z axis.]

Does anyone know how to fix this? It essentially needs to lock the z-axis when applying the quaternion.

Here is the basic code:

```
//Box natural direction
let vB = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

//Cable direction
let vC = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0).normalize();

//Quatonion
let q = new THREE.Quaternion();
q.setFromUnitVectors(vB, vC);

//Box with connection
const boxG = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 8, 10);           
const boxM = new THREE.Mesh(boxG, matSS);

const conG = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 2, 16);
conG.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);

const conM = new THREE.Mesh(conG, matSS);
conM.translateZ(5);
boxM.applyQuaternion(q);            
boxM.add(conM);
scene.add(boxM);

//Cable to connect
const cabG = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.25, 0.25, 100, 16);
cabG.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
const cabM = new THREE.Mesh(cabG, matBL);
const cabP = vC.clone().setLength(50);
cabM.applyQuaternion(q);
cabM.position.set(cabP.x,cabP.y,cabP.z);
   
scene.add(cabM);
```

Tried a number of things like rotating the Z-axis back, but that did not work.

Comment: Any chance you could put up a working demo in Jsfiddle or Codepen? I have a few theories, but would like to test them out first.

Comment: Use `mesh.lookAt( x, y, z )` -- if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you. We tested that a little earlier today and came to the conclusion that was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how `z-axis` to be locked (respect to which plane), solution varies.

### Solution #1: Polar angle rotation respect to Z-axis + azimuthal angle rotation in X-Y plane

In case `box natural direction` coincides `pole`,
it's possible to control the box direction by simply specifying another box-axis (e.g. rotation axis) to adjust `roll` angle.

```
//Box natural direction
let vB = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

//Cable direction
let vC = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0).normalize();

//Quatonion
let q = new THREE.Quaternion();
q.setFromUnitVectors(vB, vC);

console.log("q before", q);

// Box's rotation axis 
let vAxisFrom = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0); // or (1, 0, 0)
// Axis of quaternion rotation (from vB to vC)   
let vAxisTo = vB.clone().cross(vC).normalize();

let q_roll = new THREE.Quaternion();
q_roll.setFromUnitVectors(vAxisFrom, vAxisTo);
q.multiply(q_roll);

console.log("q after", q);
```

### Solution #2: Polar angle rotation respect to Y-axis + azimuthal angle rotation in Z-X plane

In this case, composing quaternion as a combination of `yaw angle rotation around Y-axis` and `pitch angle rotation around X axis` would be a simple way.

```
//Box natural direction
let vB = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

//Cable direction
let vC = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0).normalize();

//Quatonion
let q = new THREE.Quaternion();
 
let vAxisInPlane = vC.clone().setY(0.0).normalize();
if (vAxisInPlane.lengthSq() < 1.0) {
    q.setFromUnitVectors(vB, vC);
}
else {
    q.setFromUnitVectors(vB, vAxisInPlane);
    console.log("q before", q);
    let q_pitch =  new THREE.Quaternion();
    q_pitch.setFromUnitVectors(vAxisInPlane, vC);
    q.premultiply(q_pitch);
    console.log("q after", q);
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem for cable direction 1,1,0. However, it now breaks at 0,1,1 and 1,1,1 and probably other combinations too.

Comment: Since the first solution is based on `z-axis polar angle rotation` + `azimuthal angle rotation in xy plane`, the rotation around original z is to be aligned respect to **x-y plane**.